# Installation of rgdal fails in Gentoo with inverser.c include directive

Tags: r, gentoo, rgdal

I am trying to install rgdal (a dependency of gstat) in R on a Calculate Linux (effectively a generic Gentoo) clean installation. I have sci-libs/gdal installed. Here are the last few lines of output:

```
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -I/usr/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal  -I"/home/wjc721/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -march=x86-64 -pipe  -c OGR_write.cpp -o OGR_write.o

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-g++ -I/usr/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal  -I"/home/wjc721/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -march=x86-64 -pipe  -c gdal-bindings.cpp -o gdal-bindings.o

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal  -I"/home/wjc721/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -march=x86-64 -pipe  -c init.c -o init.o

x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc -std=gnu99 -I/usr/lib64/R/include -DNDEBUG -I/usr/include/gdal  -I"/home/wjc721/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.2/sp/include"   -fpic  -O2 -march=x86-64 -pipe  -c inverser.c -o inverser.o
inverser.c:3:22: fatal error: projects.h: No such file or directory
 #include <projects.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
```

Existing answers on Stackoverflow are for Linux distributions other than Gentoo. They suggest installation of packages (in Debian) such as libgdal1h, libgdal1-dev, libproj-dev and gdal-bin, none of which exist in Gentoo.

Any help would be very much appreciated! It was working fine on the previous version of Calculate :(

Thanks,
Bill

Edit: I upgraded R from v3.2.2 to 3.3.2 and gdal from 2.0.2-r3 to 2.0.3. This did not help, the error is the same.

Comment: Try to unmerge and merge again `sci-libs/proj` package, worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem. Upgrading to proj-4.9.2 did the trick.

Comment: Thanks francois, that worked but only with the following versions: dev-lang/R-3.3.2, sci-libs/gdal-2.0.3 and as you suggest, sci-libs/proj-4.9.2.

Comment: Same here. Thank you for the hint!